# Scss :last-child selector problem with attribute selector

Tags: css, sass

Here is the html:

```
<div class="card">
   <!-- First child -->
   <div class="card__side">  
      Front
   </div>
   <!-- Last child -->
   <div class="card__side--back-1">
      Back
   </div>
</div>
```

and here is the scss code:

```
.card {
    perspective: 150rem;
    position: relative;
    height: 50rem;
    
    &:hover &__side {
        &:first-child {
            transform: rotateY(180deg);
        }
    
        &:last-child {
            transform: rotateY(0deg);
        }
    }

    [class*="card__side"] {
        font-size: 2rem;

        height: 50rem;
        transition: all .8s ease;
        position: absolute;
        width: 100%;
        backface-visibility: hidden;

        &:first-child {
            background-color: $color-white;
        }
    
        &:last-child {
            background-color: $color-white;
            transform: rotateY(180deg);
        }
    }
}
```

when I use the class name `card__side--back-1`, the selector `[class*="card__side"]` is working but the selector `:last-child` is not working,

however when I change the class name to `card__side` for both of the divs, it works.

I know I can give different classes for the task but asking to learn the main reason behind this. This is my first post so I hope I am making it right. Thanks in advance.

when I change the class name to `card__side` for both of the divs, it works.

Answer (score 0):

I've solved it, the selectors work fine now.

the problem was at the `&:hover &__side`selector at line 5.

I've changed the 5th line of the scss code to `&:hover [class*="card__side"]` now it selects.

```
.card {
    perspective: 150rem;
    position: relative;
    height: 50rem;
    
    &:hover [class*="card__side"] {
        &:first-child {
            transform: rotateY(180deg);
        }
    
        &:last-child {
            transform: rotateY(0deg);
        }
    }

    [class*="card__side"] {
        font-size: 2rem;

        height: 50rem;
        transition: all .8s ease;
        position: absolute;
        width: 100%;
        backface-visibility: hidden;

        &:first-child {
            background-color: $color-white;
        }
    
        &:last-child {
            background-color: $color-white;
            transform: rotateY(180deg);
        }
    }
    

}
```